# Magento 2.3.4: How to find out the configuration key value for `Enable this Solution` for a Payment Method?

Tags: magento2.3, core-config-data, klarnacheckout

Our Magento store recently got Klarna extension integrated in itself as another payment method. I need to find out the configuration key value for the field 'Enable this Solution'. Where do I find this bit of information so that I can pass this in the code below? payment_us_klarna_section_klarna_klarna_kp_required_active doesn't return the value.

```
echo "Store Config Value: " . $block->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment_us_klarna_section_klarna_klarna_kp_required_active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Here is the screenshot for the field that I need the configuration key value of.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config path should be:

```
payment/klarna_kp/active
```

Now your code should be:

```
echo "Store Config Value: " . $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/klarna_kp/active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Make sure `$this->_scopeConfig` is the instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

Comment: This displayed 0 indicating the solution was disabled. Perfect answer Sohel.

Comment: Can I use objectmanager to instantiate Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface since I need this configuration value only in the product details page?

Comment: Sohel Sir, please look at my issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317446/magento-2-getting-error-inside-tracking-shipment-popup