# Magento 2: Getting error inside tracking shipment popup

Tags: magento-shipping, temando, magento2.2.11

I am getting error "Shipment with id "" does not exist." inside tracking shipment popup in case of Magento shipping career.

I am attaching the image file for better understanding:
[image]

Please help me out to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.